# I was unable to install the latest nodejs package on my parrot os. i had version 12 installed but wasn't working when i tried create a new react app

Tags: node.js, npm

error:
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/farsh/.npm/_logs/2022-07-28T20_20_28_180Z-debug.log

Comment: "Error: EACCES: permission denied" and "The operation was rejected by your operating system, It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user" tells you the story...

Comment: And "If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running the command again as root/Administrator." tells you the possible solution

Answer (score 1):

change permission in pwd directory you want to create

Like this :

```
$ sudo chown $(whoami) -R /path
```

if doesn't work, try this :

```
$ sudo chown 777 -R /path
```